# JQuery: Pass the TD into a javascript object so I can appendTo objects

Tags: jquery

I'm dynamically generating a table.

and when I am generating a TD , I wish to run a javascript to appendTo some hyperlinks into the TD.

may I know how I can achieve that?

```
function appendTo(value, value, td){
 td.appendTo<...  hyperlinks>
}
```

Comment: Is that all the code you've tried?

Comment: honestly speaking I don't really know how to do that.. I don't even know how to call the javascript to append the hyperlink when is generating the TD.